# Changing class using Directives in meteor with Angular2 (Dropdown List)

Tags: angular, meteor, typescript

I'm developing an app using Meteor with angular 2 and typescript.

What I want is to click on a menu item and add a class `open` to the parent.

To do it, I have a link with the class `nav-dropdown-toggle` and when I click on it, my directive gets the event and changes the variable `_open` (this part is working because I can see the logs)

The problem is that sometimes it works, but others I just only see the logs and it doesn't add or remove the class.

What I'm doing wrong?

This is my directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '.nav-dropdown',
    host: {
        '[class.open]': '_open',
    }
})
export class NavDropdownDirective {

    private _open = false;

    /**
    * Checks if the dropdown menu is open or not.
    */
    isOpen() { 
        console.log("Open => " + this._open); 
        return this._open; 
    }

    /**
    * Opens the dropdown menu.
    */
    open() {
        this._open = true;
    }

    /**
    * Closes the dropdown menu .
    */
    close() {
        this._open = false;
    }

    /**
    * Toggles the dropdown menu.
    */
    toggle() {
        if (this.isOpen()) {
            this.close();
        } else {
            this.open();
        }
        console.log("toggle pushed: _open = "+ this._open);
    }
}

/**
* Allows the dropdown to be toggled via click.
*/
@Directive({
    selector: '.nav-dropdown-toggle',
})
export class NavDropdownToggleDirective{
    constructor(private dropdown: NavDropdownDirective) {}

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    toggleOpen($event:any) {
        console.log($event);
        $event.preventDefault();
        this.dropdown.toggle();

        console.log("is open? => "+this.dropdown.isOpen());
    }
}

export const NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES = [NavDropdownDirective, NavDropdownToggleDirective];
```

My module:

```
//imports
...
import { NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES }      from './shared/nav-dropdown.directive'    

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ...,
    ...
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    declarations: [
        ...,
        NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
    ],
    providers: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My Layout:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    template
})
@InjectUser("user")
export class FullLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
    user: Meteor.User;
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit()
    {

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this._userNotificationSub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

My HTML

```
    <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['dashboard']"><i class="icon-home"></i> Dashboard </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown" routerLinkActive="open">
                <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="icon-people"></i> Employees</a>
                <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['employees/list']"><i class="icon-list"></i> List </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['employees/new']"><i class="icon-user"></i> New </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';

import template from './dashboard.component.html';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard-children',
    template
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( ) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

And my routes:

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
    {path: '', component: LoginComponent, data: {title: 'Login'}, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'app', component: FullLayoutComponent, data: {title: 'Home'}, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, data: {title: 'Dashboard'}},
            {
                path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent, data: {title: 'Employees'},
                children: [
                    {path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
                    {path: 'list', component: EmployeesListComponent, data: {title: 'Listado'}},
                    {path: 'new', component: EmployeeNewComponent, data: {title: 'New'}},
                    {path: 'edit/:id', component: EmployeeEditComponent, data: {title: 'Edit'}},
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {path: '**', component: Error404Component, data: {title: 'Error'}}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working. I noticed that my problem is different..

Anyone can take a look at this code If needs to change a class with directives